# getting CmisInvalidArgumentException: Extensions tree too wide! while using apache chemistry opencmis

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am a newbie to Apache Chemistry openCMIS.

I am trying to pull a PDF document from the Alfresco repository using its Id.
The id is something similar to workspace://SpacesStore/b91dc42c-1644-4246-b3x9-bxx6f0be4wf3

> CmisObject object = getSession().getObject(Id);

I am getting the below exception while execute the above line.

> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Parsing exception!

The Exception object does not contain the stackTrace and it contains the cause as below.

> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisInvalidArgumentException: Extensions tree too wide!

But, I dont understand what I am missing. I have another drupal application, that pulls the same PDF without any issue. But this issue happens when I do it thru my java program.

Can anyone please help me out find what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE (ATTACHING THE CODE)**

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "admin");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "admin");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://192.168.64.130:8080/alfresco/service/cmis");

    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCALE_ISO3166_COUNTRY, "us");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCALE_ISO639_LANGUAGE, "en");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCALE_VARIANT, "");

    Repository soleRepository = (Repository)sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0);
    Session session = soleRepository.createSession();

    String Id = "workspace://SpacesStore/c271a8b1-9fe6-4c43-8b9d-c09935248d18";

    CmisObject object = session.getObject(Id);  

    System.out.println(object);
```

Comment: If possible, please provide a snippet of your code.

Comment: Does this happen only on this alfresco node? Cmis has some hardcoded limitations and your node could have too many values in a property or other complexity on its metadata

Comment: I updated the code snippet

Comment: Check if it works with other nodes. If it does work, open the node with the issue in the node browser and verify if it has something particularly complex.

Comment: The code you added does not compile...

Comment: I tried your code (after some fix) and it works for me. You need to check your node and see what has wrong.

Comment: I think it would be a version compatibility issue. My Alfresco is 4.X and openCMIS is 0.9 
My other part of project uses same openCMIS libraries with Alfresco 3.X. It works there. But not with Alfresco 4.X

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following discussion: [jeff potts on alfresco forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cmis-error-when-setting-multivalued-field-100-values)